# React Native - getItemLayout setting for multiple columns

Tags: react-native

I want to implement a scrollToIndex function for my flatlist. However, it prompts and out of range error. I am wondering is it related to getItemLayout inside flatlist if it is single column only.

```
 getItemLayout = (data, index) => (
    { length: win.width*0.335, offset: (win.width*0.335)*index, index }
  )

render(){
  return(
<FlatList
            numColumns={3}
            ref={(ref) => { this.dataList = ref; }}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => this._renderItem(item, index)}
            data={this.state.data}
            extraData={this.state}
           getItemLayout={this.getItemLayout}//required for scrollToIndex
            style={{ flex: 1, paddingBottom: win.height * 0.02 }}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}

        />
)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you set `numColumns` above 1 ScrollView will call `getItemLayout` once per row instead of per item. So it's better to think of the index as "rowIndex" rather than item index.

I discovered this when my ScrollView got jumpy after loading around 17 rows of content or 51 items, and it would at certain scroll points jump 1 row up/down.

Answer (score 1):

## React Native FlatList getItemLayout for multiple columns

The idea is the FlatList just needs to know for this index, how tall is it (length), how do I jump to it (offset) and pass back the current index. Not sure why they need the index as that doesn't change.

```
const FIXED_ITEM_HEIGHT = 100
const NUM_COLUMNS = 3

getItemLayout = (data, index) => ({
  length: FIXED_ITEM_HEIGHT,
  offset: FIXED_ITEM_HEIGHT * Math.floor(index / NUM_COLUMNS),
  index
})
```

**HOWEVER**... This feature doesn't work as it's supposed to. It fires on scroll but the index doesn't change. There are many known issues at the time of this writing so don't use it in production.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20467

So currently Facebook gets an unlike on this feature.